# OSX & Windows desktop background OpenGL context

Tags: windows, macos, opengl

I was wondering if there is any way to change the background of either Windows or Mac to be run by an application containing an OpenGL context and render things in real time to the background? I think windows stores a copy of the background image to be rendered, so I don't expect it to be possible there.